# Chi-squared goodness of fit test in Python: way too low p-values, but the fitting function is correct

Tags: python, scipy, chi-squared, p-value, goodness-of-fit

Despite having searched for two day in related questions, I have not really found an answer to this Problem yet...

In the following code, I generate  n  normally distributed random variables, which are then represented in a histogram:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 10000                        # number of generated random variables 
x = np.random.normal(0,1,n)      # generate n random variables

# plot this in a non-normalized histogram:
plt.hist(x, bins='auto', normed=False)    

# get the arrays containing the bin counts and the bin edges:
histo, bin_edges = np.histogram(x, bins='auto', normed=False)
number_of_bins = len(bin_edges)-1
```

After that, a curve fitting function and its parameters are found. 
It is normally distributed with the parameters a1 and b1, and scaled with scaling_factor to meet the fact that the sample is unnormalized.
It indeed fits the histogram quite well:

```
import scipy as sp

a1, b1 = sp.stats.norm.fit(x)

scaling_factor = n*(x.max()-x.min())/number_of_bins

plt.plot(x_achse,scaling_factor*sp.stats.norm.pdf(x_achse,a1,b1),'b')
```

[Here's the plot of the histogram with the fitting function in red.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBJVT.png)

After that, I want to test how well this function fits the histogram using the chi-squared test.
This test uses the observed values and the expected values in those points. To calculate the expected values, I first calculate the location of the middle of each bin, this information is contained in the array x_middle. I then calculate the value of the fitting function at the middle point of each bin, which gives the expected_value array:

```
observed_values = histo

bin_width = bin_edges[1] - bin_edges[0]

# array containing the middle point of each bin:
x_middle = np.linspace(  bin_edges[0] + 0.5*bin_width,    
           bin_edges[0] + (0.5 + number_of_bins)*bin_width,
           num = number_of_bins) 

expected_values = scaling_factor*sp.stats.norm.pdf(x_middle,a1,b1)
```

Plugging this into the chisquare function of Scipy, I get p-values of approximately e-5 to e-15 order of magnitude, which tells me the fitting function does not describe the histogram:

```
print(sp.stats.chisquare(observed_values,expected_values,ddof=2))
```

But this is not true, the function fits the histogram very well!

Does anybody know where I made a mistake?

Thanks a lot!!
Charles

p.s.: I set the number of delta degrees of freedom to 2, because the 2 parameters a1 and b1 are estimated from the sample. I tried using other ddof, but the results were still as poor!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your calculation of the end-point of the array `x_middle` is off by one; it should be:

```
x_middle = np.linspace(bin_edges[0] + 0.5*bin_width,    
                       bin_edges[0] + (0.5 + number_of_bins - 1)*bin_width,
                       num=number_of_bins)
```

Note the extra `- 1` in the second argument of `linspace()`.

A more concise version is

```
x_middle = 0.5*(bin_edges[1:] + bin_edges[:-1])
```

A different (and possibly more accurate) approach to computing `expected_values` is to use the differences of the CDF, instead of approximating those differences using the PDF in the middle of each interval:

```
In [75]: from scipy import stats

In [76]: cdf = stats.norm.cdf(bin_edges, a1, b1)

In [77]: expected_values = n * np.diff(cdf)
```

With that calculation, I get the following result from the chi-squared test:

```
In [85]: stats.chisquare(observed_values, expected_values, ddof=2)
Out[85]: Power_divergenceResult(statistic=61.168393496775181, pvalue=0.36292223875686402)
```

Comment: Your suggestion for the the calculation of  'expected_values' works better indeed. Which makes sense from a mathematical point of view, since this newly obtained array corresponds to the integral under the fitting curve (if multiplied by n), which the bin count should correspond to. Thank you!